# electron/vuejs - uikit modal not covering entire screen when inside sub components

Tags: html, css, vue.js, electron

I'm wondering why the modal looks like this (dark background not fully covering the top and bottom) when its inside a subsection of the overall code.

[image]

Modal code `Modal.vue`

```
<template>
    <!-- This is the modal -->
    <div id="my-id" uk-modal>
        <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-body">
            <h2 class="uk-modal-title">Add Group</h2>
            <div class="uk-modal-body">
                <div>
                    Name:
                </div>
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
            <div class="uk-modal-footer">
                <div class="uk-float-right">
                    <button class="uk-modal-close" type="button">Ok</button>
                    <button class="uk-modal-close" type="button">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's where I'm putting it `Sidebar.html`

```
<section ref="wrapper">
    <div>
        <button v-on:click="update_files">Refresh</button>
        <button v-on:click="select_root">Select folder</button>
    </div>
    <article v-for="(folder, index) in folders">
        <header>{{ folder }}</header>
        <div>
            <button v-on:click="add(folder)">Add</button>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(file, index) in files[folder]" v-bind:data-folder="folder" v-on:click="load_file({folder, file})">
                {{ file }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </article>

    <!-- This is a button toggling the modal -->
    <button uk-toggle="target: #my-id" type="button">Open modal</button>
    <Modal /> 
</section>
```

Where `<Modal />` is the modal

Sidebar is a subset of App `App.html`

```
<div id="app">
    <template v-if="store.state.General.root">
        <aside id="sidebar">
            <sidebar/>
        </aside>
        <main>
            <writing/>
        </main>
    </template>
    <!-- <router-view class='main-view' v-if="store.state.General.folder"/> -->
    <div id='select_folder' v-else>
        <div>
            <div>
                Select a folder to begin
            </div>
            <button v-on:click="select_root">Select folder</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <Modal /> -->
</div>
```

You can find the source code here (open source) (use `dev` branch): https://github.com/FunnyB0y/forgit-me-not

Comment: I think you haven't pushed the latest code to GitHub, since I can't see `Modal.vue`. Regardless, could you provide the css you're using? That's almost certainly where the error lies.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat I haven't merged it with the master branch yet, it's on the `dev` branch

Comment: Huh, for some reason I didn't see `dev` when I checked a moment ago.

Comment: I'm still not seeing `Modal.vue` even on `dev`.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Ah woops, I thought I pushed it already, seems like I forgot to fill in the credentials. It's there now, just checked. It's inside `src/components`

Comment: Try changing `<div id="my-id" uk-modal>` to `<div id="my-id" class="uk-modal">`? I don't have any experience with uikit, but in their example that's how they do it: https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/modal.html#usage

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat Strange, if I copy your examples, it doesn't work. The buttons don't show up and the modal doesn't pop up if I click my original button

Comment: Huh, odd. Well, sorry I can't help with that, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design. The modal is only as big as it's content (and padding). By setting `.uk-open>.uk-modal-dialog` to `height: 100vh` you'll get it as big as the window (but you have to adjust some inner padding, etc to get rid of the scroll bar).

Comment: There's still an offset from the top

Comment: Yes, that's due to the margin around the modal. You have to understand CSS to be handle to adjust those kind of things

Comment: it was the margin not the height.